# replace "double low-9 quotation mark" with php

Tags: php, str-replace

I have finally made a parser to an old computer generated text-file. Now the problem is character encoding. Or at least that's what I think.

I have tried lots of methods found in stackoverflow to replace double low-9 quotation mark with php. No success so far.

This is my code:

```
$lines = file("RECEIVE_modified.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$result = str_replace("\0xE2\0x80\0x9E", "&auml;", $lines);
```

I have tried `„,` and other possibilities instead of `\0xE2\0x80\0x9E`.

Code works, of course, but what is the right syntax for that stupid quotation mark?

Comment: Do you mind posting a sample of `RECEIVE_modified.txt` so we can easily test before posting an answer?

Comment: Some text„ier     12345, 0, 270317125439, 270317135729, 934, 1262 etc...

Comment: It would be most useful to inspect the file with a hex editor to get the exact bytes used for that character…

Comment: If I did everything correctly, exact bytecount is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done by the following:

```
$result = utf8_decode($lines);
```

Thank you deceze for putting my head straight!